# Commutativity Variation and derivative

Tags: differentiation, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

When in general is true that

$\nabla_{\mu}\delta=\delta\nabla_{\mu}$

where $\nabla_{\mu}$ is covariant derivative?

I was thinking this when one has to find the equations of motion for example in general relativity and one swap the nabla with the delta.